# Using LESS @import (reference) syntax with webpack... does it break de-dupe?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

I am working with a React app w/webpack configured to de-duplicate LESS files imported into multiple stylesheets with the standard `@import 'my-file.less'` syntax.

If webpack sees that `variables.less` is imported by 2 children .less files, it will only add the code from `variables.less` once in the output bundle.

If I, instead, use the `reference` syntax with my `@import` statements, will this prevent webpack from being able to de-dupe as outlined above?